# Unable to set inactive account lockout

Tags: command-line, user-management

I am trying set the default inactivity period to 30 days using `sudo userdadd -D -f 30`. The command doesn't give me any errors, but when I type `/usr/sbin/useradd -D | /bin/grep INACTIVE` to check if the change has been made, I still get -1.

I went to check `/etc/default/useradd` and it says **INACTIVE=30**, however the above grep command still outputs INACTIVE -1. Similarly `useradd -D` also outputs -1.

My guess is that somewhere in the Ubuntu system (20.04 by the way), something is still setting the inactive period to -1. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Read `man -a passwd ; man chage` and even `man -k PAM`.

Comment: Read them all. Here are the findings:

1 - passwd -i disables an account after the password has been inactive for some days. I need all accounts to get locked after not logging in for 30 days, so this one is not what I need.

2 - chage -I is closer to what I need, but I'm still getting the -1

3 - PAM is already enabled to lockout after 3 failed logins. Not what I need at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing here is that when executed by an unprivileged user, `useradd -D` can't read the `/etc/default/useradd` file, because it is only readable by `root`:

```
$ ls -l /etc/default/useradd
-rw------- 1 root root 1195 Jun 22 14:43 /etc/default/useradd
```

Instead, it prints the *compiled in* default values from the shadow package's `src/useradd.c` file:

```
/*
 * These defaults are used if there is no defaults file.
 */
static gid_t def_group = 100;
static const char *def_gname = "other";
static const char *def_home = "/home";
static const char *def_shell = "";
static const char *def_template = SKEL_DIR;
static const char *def_create_mail_spool = "no";

static long def_inactive = -1;
static const char *def_expire = "";
```

So you need to use

```
sudo useradd -D | /bin/grep INACTIVE
```

instead.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH for this great answer. This is just what I needed!! One last question: after reading the man pages pointed by waltinator I'm not sure these settings will achieve what I want: Do these accounts expire after N days or after N days of inactivity AFTER a password has expired (meaning the setting wll be useless without password expiration enabled)?

Comment: @AR I believe it's the latter - the inactivity period is a "grace period" during which a user is still permitted to log in, but must immediately change their password (see `man 5 shadow`). But you should probably post that as a separate question.